# Desktop Application using titanium

Tags: desktop-application, titanium

Is titanium desktop application supports PHP and mysql? or using an ajax? Should I use xampp to do this? or any suggestions you have.
**Thank you very much**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they support PHP, and as I know, no, they don't support mySQL.

But, they support a SQL database, using SQLite.

mySQL is a database server, made for various users and huge programs. Titanium is made for local (Desktop and mobile) apps, and it uses SQLite for databases.

SQLite is smaller than MySQL, don't use "users", saves databases as single files, and is a normal relational SQL database, so, you can easely port your SQL program to work in Titanium.

[SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)

[SQLite reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html)

[Titanium Database API](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest/Titanium.Database-module)

Answer (score 0):

According to their official page [here](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development) they do support PHP. Don't know about MySql or Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby, PHP or Python even if I think mostly of the tasks can be done using simple js (Titanium exposes a lot of platform related api as js objects).
You can also mix those languages.

Answer (score 0):

if you use phpinfo() and print output into your debug window you will see that PHP on Titanium Desktop has mysql extensions compiled on it + PDO. In that way you can connect to mysql server directly via PHP. Also new mysqlnd extension is available for less memory usage.
Many extensions are available: SOAP, xslt, simplexml, curl etc... And PHP 5.3.1. You can also load external extension via dl() if they are compiled at same PHP API Level and for the same architecture (32/64 bit).